# Perform CRUD in REST API with URL

Tags: rest, stripe-payments, restful-url

I'm using Stripe API(REST) and I need to put a link in email where user can directly unsubscribe/delete subscription(https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing).
I need to know if it is possible to put the arguments and operation in a URL so that when user clicks it, Stripe api is called and subscription is cancelled.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

`Cancelling` subscriptions from Stripe API requires your `Secret Key` which you should NEVER expose in the front end and made public because user will have access to your stripe account in that case.

Saying that, what you could do is to expose an endpoint in your own web server, which you will need to

1) create a on time use token which you can look up your customer and related subscriptions; include the token in your URL send to the user

2) when user click the the url, verify the token (valid non expired) and find the customer and subscriptions

3) Call stripe API with your secret keys to cancel the subscription for the customer.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. 
Yes I'm aware of the fact that secrect key is not meant to be passed publically but if we ignore the secret key for a moment, is it generally possible without having to expose an endpoint in my own web server?

Comment: Stripe relies on keys to identify the merchant etc. So no, the link without keys will not work in this case.